# Gimp 2.10.18 does not highlight selection if it's all with alpha

Tags: gimp

When I select an area that contains a completely opaque color part and an alpha color part, after copying and pasting it, it highlights the selection for only a part of the selected area.

Also, if the whole selected area is with alpha, after pasting the whole layer it is not selected/highlighted, so I can't work with it!

But the real selection is the whole area correctly, so the color changes if I paste it twice.

It's a bug? Or how to make it select all area after copy-paste?

Draw something as full color and with alpha:

[image]

select it:

[image]

copy and paste, see that the highlighted selection is partial:

[image]

draw something all with alpha:

[image]

select it:

[image]

copy-paste, see that there isn't a selection at all:

[image]

(Gimp 2.10.18 on Ubuntu)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. It's just the way GIMP works. What are you actually trying to achieve here?  Why does having a square selection after pasting even matter?  Did you promote the floating selection to a new layer after pasting?  Have you disabled the layer boundary?  If you do have a new layer, have you tried Ctrl+A to select all? Can you perhaps take a screenshot including your layers panel?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the same as your issue, but see this [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131299/rectangle-select-tool-moves-the-image-instead-of-creating-a-selection-in-gimp/131300#131300) I gave to a similar question.